# CSS Grid Max Width Container

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS Grid to create a responsive two column layout on larger screens. Currently my code works well however I want the header, banner and footer sections to be full width and the content inside of it to be centered width a 1200px width. Currently the whole container box is 1200px however the header, banner and footer do not extend to the whole width of the page.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
@import 'layout.css';
@import 'responsive.css';
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #666;
}
.logo img{
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #333;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #333;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #333;
}
a {
    color: #007acc;
}
a:hover {
    color: #00aaff;
}
#header {
    background: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 15px 15px;
}   
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}  
nav li {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}  
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.banner {
    background: #007acc;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.banner h1 {
    color: #FFF;
}
p.subheading {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.main-content {
    padding: 30px 15px;
}
.post-listing {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 30px 30px;
}
.post-listing h2 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
a.read-more {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #007acc;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.1;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
a.read-more:hover {
    background: #00aaff;
}
.social-share {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.social-share ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.social-share li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#sidebar {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#sidebar ul {
  margin-left: 20px;   
}
#sidebar li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#footer {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd"
    "banner"
    "mc"
    "ft";
}

#header {
    grid-area: hd;
}
.banner {
    grid-area: banner;
}
.main-content { 
    grid-area: mc;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "main"
    "sidebar";
}
#main {
    grid-area: main;
}
#sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}
#footer {
    grid-area: ft;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
   .container {
       grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 1200px);
       justify-content: center
    }
    .main-content { 
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "main main sidebar";
        grid-gap: 60px;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Space Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header id="header">
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="My Space Blog"></a>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="banner">
            <h1>My Space Blog</h1>
            <p class="subheading">
                Your go-to blog for all the latest news on space and interstellar activities.
            </p>    
         </div><!-- end banner -->

         <div class="main-content">
            <main id="main" role="main">
                <article class="post-listing">
                    <h2>The Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence</h2>
                    <img src="img/extraterrestial.jpg" alt="AI satellite to detect extraterrestial life">
                    <p>
                        For centuries, humans have looked to the stars and wondered if we are alone in the universe. 
                        The idea that there might be intelligent life beyond our planet has captivated our imaginations and fueled our curiosity.
                    </p>
                    <p>Scientists have been searching for signs of extraterrestrial intelligence for decades, using a variety of methods and 
                    technologies. One of the most well-known and controversial of these methods is the search for radio signals from other civilizations.</p>
                    <a href="blog-post.html" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                </article>
    
            </main>
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <h2>All Posts:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="blog-post.html">The Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exploring the Surface of Mars: The Mars Rover Missions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Search for Habitable Planets: Exoplanet Exploration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Future of Space Travel: Challenges and Opportunities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">From Sputnik to SpaceX: A Brief History of Spaceflight</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div><!-- end main-content -->

        <footer id="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2023 All Rights Reserved.</p>
         </footer>
    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you put header and footer in `.container`.

Comment: I am aware of this, but what is the workaround using CSS Grid?

Comment: in add of what wrote Shuo, you have a strange grid! Grid but with flexbox in, which is ok for inside elements of grid cell, but not to define the cell! Go there https://cssgridbuilder.com/, on top click on Empty "select layouts". You have grid layouts already done similar of what you are needing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple update to your code if you cannot change the structure:

```
.container {
  grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd"
    ". banner ."
    ". mc ."
    "ft ft ft";
}
```

Then

```css
@media (min-width: 900px) {
   .container {
       grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 1200px) 1fr;
   }
}
```

Full code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
@import 'layout.css';
@import 'responsive.css';
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #666;
}
.logo img{
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #333;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #333;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #333;
}
a {
    color: #007acc;
}
a:hover {
    color: #00aaff;
}
#header {
    background: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 15px 15px;
}   
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}  
nav li {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}  
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.banner {
    background: #007acc;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.banner h1 {
    color: #FFF;
}
p.subheading {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.main-content {
    padding: 30px 15px;
}
.post-listing {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 30px 30px;
}
.post-listing h2 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
a.read-more {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #007acc;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.1;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
a.read-more:hover {
    background: #00aaff;
}
.social-share {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.social-share ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.social-share li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#sidebar {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#sidebar ul {
  margin-left: 20px;   
}
#sidebar li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#footer {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd"
    ". banner ."
    ". mc ."
    "ft ft ft";
}

#header {
    grid-area: hd;
}
.banner {
    grid-area: banner;
}
.main-content { 
    grid-area: mc;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "main"
    "sidebar";
}
#main {
    grid-area: main;
}
#sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}
#footer {
    grid-area: ft;
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
   .container {
       grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 1200px) 1fr;
       justify-content: center
    }
    .main-content { 
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "main main sidebar";
        grid-gap: 60px;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Space Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header id="header">
            <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="My Space Blog"></a>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="banner">
            <h1>My Space Blog</h1>
            <p class="subheading">
                Your go-to blog for all the latest news on space and interstellar activities.
            </p>    
         </div><!-- end banner -->

         <div class="main-content">
            <main id="main" role="main">
                <article class="post-listing">
                    <h2>The Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence</h2>
                    <img src="img/extraterrestial.jpg" alt="AI satellite to detect extraterrestial life">
                    <p>
                        For centuries, humans have looked to the stars and wondered if we are alone in the universe. 
                        The idea that there might be intelligent life beyond our planet has captivated our imaginations and fueled our curiosity.
                    </p>
                    <p>Scientists have been searching for signs of extraterrestrial intelligence for decades, using a variety of methods and 
                    technologies. One of the most well-known and controversial of these methods is the search for radio signals from other civilizations.</p>
                    <a href="blog-post.html" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                </article>
    
            </main>
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <h2>All Posts:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="blog-post.html">The Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exploring the Surface of Mars: The Mars Rover Missions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Search for Habitable Planets: Exoplanet Exploration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Future of Space Travel: Challenges and Opportunities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">From Sputnik to SpaceX: A Brief History of Spaceflight</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div><!-- end main-content -->

        <footer id="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2023 All Rights Reserved.</p>
         </footer>
    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a good start, content inside the header isn't centered at 1200px though. I can change the code if it needs to be changed so feel free to do that as long as it gives me the standard 1200px width centered containers within header, banner and footer with full width background colors using CSS Grid

Comment: @zestzahir what do you mean isn't centred?

Comment: its centered at full width, the background color of it should be full width but inner items should be centered at 1200px